# How to Format Excel Bar Chart Date Axis Tied to Pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, bar-chart

In the barchart below I want to format the X-axis to be "7/21". You can see that I've formatted in my pivot chart but that didn't help.  Then in the Format Axis panel at the bottom under the Number section the formatting options for Date are there but nothing happens if I press the Add button.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just checked, and I have exactly the same issue, whatever I change nothing happens (I have Excel for Office 365 16.0.12527.20880 64 bit)

seems to be a bug.

Comment: i have version 16.0.130001.20338 64-bit, and it seems to be fine. Can you update yours and check if the issue persists?

Comment: I've a work pc, unfortunately I don't control updates.

Comment: I just tried it on 16.0.13426.20308 and nothing happens when I change the formatting using this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set it this way:

1. Right-click on the date button on the pivot chart, then select Field settings.
2. On the windows that opens, click on Number format.
3. Set the date format, then click Ok, and OK once more. The date format should be set as you selected.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: This approach doesn't have any effect for me. The formatting remains no matter what I select.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem - the number format button would not show up in the field list. So I reset the Pivot-data source to just the rows containing the data (I had previously just selected the whole columns ($A:$J)). With that done, the button reappeared and the date-format changes worked for the graph as well. Then, after formating the whole date coulumn to "Date" in the source data, it also worked with whole coulumns as the source, although that reformating step had not been successful before changing the Pivot-Data-Source. So there seems to be a bug which keeps a coulmn from being recognised as "date" as long as something else sits there.